# Post on a REST Web Service : How can I get access to the POSTed input values?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, rest

Is there an tool(Class/Method) in the .NET Framework to transform the urlencoded string body of a Form POSTed like :

```
Id=O+mon+dieu%21&StringValue=Trop+facile&envoyer=Save
```

to, for instance, a key-value Dictionary?

```
{"Id","O mon dieu !"} {"StringValue" , "Trop facile"} {"envoyer", "Save"}
```

I guest there is a tool like this included...

FYI, it's to be used in a REST Web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method can take a URL encoded name value pairs and create a `NameValueCollection` instance with the data. It is similar to a dictionary but allows multiple values for a key, which is perfectly legal in your scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx